# Regression/Optimization models that factor in the conviction of the predictive values

Tags: regression, optimization, uncertainty, forecast-combination

This comes up in a problem I meet in practice.

Consider the classical regression of combining two predictions together to form a stronger prediction $Y 
 \sim X_1 + X_2$. Here essentially we generate a prediction  $\hat{Y}$ for every single data point. Some prediction might be noisy, but we have them regardless.

I wonder if there exists some model that only generates a prediction when the model is somewhat "highly convicted". One simple naive example of such model is,  if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both positively correlated to $Y$, we only generate a prediction when $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same sign. Otherwise we don't generate a predicted $\hat{Y}$.  We don't have prediction all the time, but we have stronger conviction for our prediction.

I am wondering if there is some existing, more mature and more systematic model  that handles this kind of problems. Ideally you would find a way to combine two predictors (better than my naive approach), and also add a penalty on the numbers of data points you don't have high conviction...

Lastly, ideally there is an R/python package implementation for that model. :)

Answer (score 0):

The most mature and systematic approach to this question is to let the uncertainty distribution guide the degree of "conviction".  The uncertainty distribution (under Bayesian or frequentist assumptions) of the $\hat{Y}$ encompasses all the information you have into its estimate.  From there, you can choose to only display or accept $\hat{Y}$ values that have sufficiently "narrow" probability distributions, e.g. $P(a < \hat{Y} < b) > \alpha$.  Other systems, like the ones you describe where you are making marginal decisions based on the predictors ($X_i$) are generally less statistically powerful than joint decisions made on all the information simultaneously.

Edit: below is some example code to illustrate the general approach with a simple linear regression.

```r
require(ggplot2)

lm1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp*wt, data = mtcars)

plot(lm1, which = 1)

yhat <- predict(lm1, se.fit = TRUE)

yhat_mean <- yhat$fit
yhat_sd <- yhat$se.fit

threshold_certainty <- 0.85
threshold_tolerance_mpg <- 1

prob_within_tolerance <- pnorm(yhat_mean + threshold_tolerance_mpg, yhat_mean, yhat_sd) -
  pnorm(yhat_mean - threshold_tolerance_mpg, yhat_mean, yhat_sd)

mtcars$color <- factor(ifelse(prob_within_tolerance > threshold_certainty, "good", "uncertain"))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = hp, col = color)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("good" = "green", "uncertain" = "red"))
```

Comment: thanks, what you said makes a lot of sense. Is there a package implementation for what you described?

Comment: Any good statistics package (R for example) can allow you to estimate the distribution of the predictions depending on your modeling assumptions.  Everything else I described would be custom code specific to how your model worked.  I added example code to the answer.